# What sort of behaviors would an Intelligence of 2 dictate for an animal?

Tags: traveller

Using the rules from the **Traveller** supplement *Animal Encounters*, I rolled up an animal that ended up being:

- Omnivorous
- Melee: Unarmed /2
- Deception /1
- Survival /1
- Stealth /0
- Recon /0
- Strength 12
- Endurance 12
- Dexterity 7
- Pack 9
- Instinct 10
- Intelligence 2
- Armor 3
- Bite attack +2dmg (+6 with bonuses)

I plan for these creatures to be the dominant medium-sized mammal on the planet, the most powerful predator to be found on 4 of the worlds 9 continents and the most powerful medium-sized omnivore in the sector. I also plan for the characters to encounter at least 2 packs. There will be an 80% chance of either fight or flight and they will have a decent chance of being able to catch some young to sell to a zoo.

But I have never used animals in **Traveller** before, so I want advice on how to roleplay them to the best of their limited intelligence and very powerful combat abilities.

One last thing

Three other GM's I have spoken to have suggested other ideas. 1 said base them on The Feral Ones from Fire Emblem Radiant Dawn, but uncontrolled, untameable and always ready to kill. The 2nd suggest basing them on omnivorous versions of Thoe Raptors from Jurassic Park 1 and 2, which can do things like open simple doors, kick open or smash through glass and weak doors and which can outsmart veteran human and, maybe, even Aslan Hunters via a mix of cunning, ruthless yet effective abilities, natural instinct and using their would be killers tendency  to think no mere animal could outsmart a hunter as good as them and the 3rd suggested basing them on a illegal part biological, part scientific and part chemical experiment by a insane, ruthless and dedicated Human  Scientist to what, he hoped, would be the greatest omnivorous predator and in history, but his research was discovered, he was either killed resisting or executed for his crimes against nature and as for his creations, the official line was that all 1,500 or so of  his creations were destroyed, but in reality 56 escaped, after just over 209 years, they now number around 19,600 of them are alive and, via their skills, have acquired the sane degree of near-legendary status as their creator hoped they would

So. What do you think to those 3 ways to use this creatures that were suggested by 3 friends of mine who are all former full time GM's for 4 RPG Games, currently part time DM's for 3 RPG Games and who  take it in turns to fulfil the roles of M, GM Advisor and GM Aid for a eighth RPG Game

Comment: Note that some editions of Traveller (and some players and GMs of any edition) consider "Instinct" to be the nonsapient's replacement for Education: A stat that allows the critter to perform complex behaviours and sequences of actions in order to overcome obstacles without having to derive and work out those methods on the spot.

Answer (score 5):

Instinct is meant to be an "Animal Cunning" type statistic. So Instinct 10 means this critter is a shrewd hunter and will not be easily tricked or trapped. The rules say to use Instinct for recon, stealth and similar "how much attention is it paying?" situations.

Pack 9 is pretty high to, so these creatures would likely form well organized packs, capable of "tactics" like encircling prey and setting simple ambushes.

The Intelligence of 2 to me means that they are minimally self-aware and capable of learning, though they're not going to be doing any sort of scientific research or investigation. They should however be trainable, though it might take some doing to convince one that it's in the creature's best interests to obey the trainer. :)

Comment: In other words, a wolf. However, I'm not sure I'd put wolves in real life as high as pack 9, so you may want to play these like the wolves in horror movies.